# dojox.grid.DataGrid is not displaying properly

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to use dojox.grid.DataGrid and dojox.data.JsonRestStore.
Somehow the data grid is not displaying properly.

What surprised me is clicking the Run button at the dojo document side :
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html
all these examples are displaying data grid properly.

Does anyone know what's going on the dojo grid?

Answer (score 0):

All the examples given in dojo datagrid are working because they are providing local data. If you want to use it in your project then u have to implement a web service that provide remote data in json format as mention in documentation regarding jsonrest store.

[Click Here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/data/JsonRestStore.html)